# Convergance using Cauchy Criterion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

let $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}$$ The sum is convergent since it satisfies the Cauchy criterion:
$$|z_{n+p} - z_n| = \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} \frac{1}{n+k}\right| \le \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{1}{n+n+1} = \frac{p}{2n+1} \to 0$$ for $n \to \infty$.

Can someone explain why and if this is true?

Comment: What is the exact limit you are trying to compute? The sum you have given is convergent because it is simply a finite sum. If you mean the behaviour as $n \rightarrow \infty$, you don't need the Cauchy criterion here, since each term of the sum will be $0$.

Comment: @tolUene what do you mean each term of the sum will be 0? The sum converges to $\log(2)$ for $n \to \infty$. I need to show that it does indeed converge before I find the value as  $n \to \infty$.

Comment: That’s not the Cauchy criterion, and it doesn’t prove convergence. The sequence (not sim) does converge, to $\ln 2,$ in fact, but this argument doesn’t prove it.

Comment: You don't have to go this far, simply bounding the original sum by $1$ would have sufficed.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I figured it was flawed. I got the answer on this exchange but it does not seem right to argue for convergance like this.

Comment: @NinadMunshi how?

Comment: The sum follows this chain of inequalities very easily $$S < \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n} = \frac{n}{n}=1$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi But what hhave you shown now? That the series is bounded? But it isn't a bi implication that convergence if and only if bounded, right?

Comment: You are correct but I figured you could prove the monotone part on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can analyse this case by elementary means. You can simply note that, since
$$
\frac{n}{n+n}\leq\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}}_{a_n} \leq \frac{n}{n+1},
$$

the sequence $(a_n)$ in bounded ($\frac 12 \leq a_n \leq 1$). The sequence is also increasing and thus convergent.

Comment: Oh, so the sum is a bounded and monotonic sequence and thus convergent?

Comment: “The sum” is meaningless here, @mathstudent23 It is not one sum. The **sequence** is bounded and increasing. Showing it is increasing amounts to showing that:$$\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2}$$

Comment: @pierrecarre you don’t need bounded below to prove it converges, but I guess it gives a lower bound for the limit.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you are right, but it was just too direct not to write it down.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy criterion is for series, first of all, and this is not a series, because there are terms in your sum for $n$ that are not in your sum for $n+1.$

That said, even for series, just because, for fixed $p,$ $\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} |a_k|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ we can not conclude the series is convergent, because $a_k=\frac{1}{k}$ has similarly:

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} \frac 1k\leq \frac p{n+1}\to 0.$$

Yet we know $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k$ diverges.

The error in this argument is really a complete misunderstanding of the [Cauchy criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test).

Comment: What would the argument be for convergence in a case like this then?

Comment: I’m sure that was asked and answered elsewhere, but in any event, that wasn’t the question here. The way I figured it was $\ln 2$ is that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n\frac1{1+k/n}$$ is a Riemann sum for $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}.$$ But there are easier proofs that it converges without knowing the value.

Comment: That was close to my question, though. I have found the value to be $\ln(2)$ using the riemann sum. I am not sure on how to show that it actually IS convergant

Comment: Well, we have a general theorem that if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then the Riemann sums for $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ converge. @mathstudent23

Comment: I guess that is my confusion. I got a theorem saying that a non-negative sequence is convergent iff it is bounded. I will see if my analysis book has the Riemann sum theorem. Thanks!

Comment: A non-negative sequence is not convergent if it is bounded. A series is convergent if the terms are non-negative and the partial sums are bounded, but **this is not a series.** The other answer uses the related rule that if a **sequence** is increasing and bounded above, then it is convergent.